# Обновить запрос на MYSQL

Tags: php, join, mysql

Всем привет, есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT lo.title FROM optical o, product p, list_optical lo WHERE o.id_product = 6 AND p.id = 6 AND o.id_optical = lo.id
```

Мне кажется, что это не очень правильно и нужно юхать Join. Так вот, подскажите, как правильно составить запрос на Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
SELECT lo.title
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN optical AS o ON o.id_product = p.id
LEFT JOIN list_optical AS lo ON lo.id = o.id_optical
WHERE p.id = '6'
```

Comment: Не работает, выдает только одну запись, в моем примере (он рабочий) выдает все записи, которые нужно.

Comment: @duddeniska, напишите, что вам реально нужно от БД. Потому что вот этот вот пример реально джойнит и действительно должен вернуть одну записи, потому что такова природа джойна.

Comment: вместо `WHERE p.id = '6'` напишите WHERE `o.id_product = 6 AND p.id = 6`

Comment: Мне нужно получить все записи в таблице list_optical у которых list_optical.id_product равен product.id и List_optical.id_optical равен optical.id